# Get dependencies from subproject within root project

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

Can't get the subproject dependencies in root build file. They isn't initialized for some reasons.
Is there a possibility to get list of dependencies from **project1** for example inside **root** ?

Pls see **copyToLib** task. It should return values from **dependencies section** of **project1**, but actually it's not.

Gradle version is 2.0

```
Root
|
|-project1
|    |-build.gradle
|-project2
|    |-build.gradle
|-core1
|    |-build.gradle
|-core2
|    |-build.gradle
|-build.gradle
|-settings.gradle
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include 'project1','project2','core1','core2'
rootProject.name="Root"
```

**project1:build.gradle**

```
version = '0.1'
dependencies {
    compile project(':core1'),
            project(':core2'),
            'org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.6.RELEASE'
}
```

**root:build.gradle**

```
subprojects{
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/eclipse.gradle"
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    repositories {
         mavenCentral()
    }
    task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
        def deps = project.configurations.compile.getAllDependencies().withType(ProjectDependency)
        for ( dep in deps ) {
            println dep.getDependencyProject().projectDir
        }
    }
    build.dependsOn(copyToLib)
}
```

Comment: I'm also searching for an answer for this. Could you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

When `project` variable is used in `subprojects` it refers to the *current* project - in this particular case - root.

You need to remove adding the task from `subprojects` closure and add the following piece of code:

```
subprojects.each { p ->
    configure(p) {
     task copyToLib << {
       def deps = p.configurations.compile.allDependencies.withType(ProjectDependency)
         for ( dep in deps ) {
           println dep.getDependencyProject().projectDir
         }
        }
        p.build.dependsOn(copyToLib)
    }
}
```

Have simplified the task (it's not of type `Copy`) - You need to differentiate task action from configuration.